# Usage of StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

> Using StaggeredGridLayoutManager/GridLayoutManager how to make grid
>   item take two spans vertically and two spans horizontally?

Comment: When the size of the items is the same, it's recommended to use a GridView, the StaggeredGridLayoutManager for the RecyclerView works better when you have different item sizes and columns or rows spans

Comment: Ya but how to achieve fist grid item like above?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can do this with StaggeredGridLayoutManager. This is simply done with GridLayoutManager. For example:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(
new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
         return (position == 0 ? 3 : 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: I used your solution and ended up with this: [http://prntscr.com/jhab7r](GridLayoutManager missing 3rd item), any idea how to solve it?